# Putting an continuously updating animated plot with other components inside a tkinter gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, graph, tkinter-canvas

I want to show a plot within one of the pages in my GUI. The data plotted, `theData` will constantly change. Whenever `theData` is changed, the value of `valueChangedtheData` is written to 1. The mapping of time and data is here:

```
xsize=100
xdata,ydata = [],[]
def data_gen():
    t = data_gen.t
    global theData
    global valueChangedtheData
    while True:
        if (valueChangedtheData == 1):
           valueChangedtheData = 0;
           t+=0.1
           val=float(theData);
           if val>1000:
               continue
           yield t, val

        else: pass


def animate(data):
    t, val = data
    if t>-1:
        xdata.append(t)
        ydata.append(val)
        if t>xsize: # Scroll to the left.
            a.set_xlim(t-xsize, t)
        line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

def on_close_figure(event):
    sys.exit(0)

data_gen.t = -1
f = plt.figure()
f.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', on_close_figure)
#f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
line, = a.plot([], [], lw=2)
a.set_ylim(0, 250)
a.set_xlim(0, xsize)
a.grid()
```

I've defined my the container of my GUI as such:

```
class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = TRUE)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        global theData;


        self.MyReading = StringVar()
        self.frames={}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
      frame = self.frames[cont]
      frame.tkraise()
```

and the page showing the plot:

```
class StartPage(Frame):                         #The Graphical Page
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = Label(self, text="StartPage")
        label.pack()
        label1 = Label(self, textvariable = controller.theData)
        label1.pack

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw() #changed from show to draw
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

And in order to start the animation and Gui:

```
root = Gui()
update_reading()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, data_gen, blit = False, interval=100, repeat = False)
root.mainloop()
```

With `update_reading()` updating the label:

```
def update_reading():
    global theData
    global valueChangedtheData
    theData = randint(1,20)             #This is just an example of the changing value
    print(theData)
    valueChangedtheData = 1;
    root.MyReading.set(str(theData));
    root.after(100,update_reading)
```

However, after adding the canvas on the page, all of the labels that rely on the variable classes would refuse to shop-up, including the value for `theData`  but the plot is graphing. Also, labels that show images would also refuse to show-up. After commenting the canvas, data mapping and animation, the label would appear back. Am I missing an important initializing code? Also, during plotting, there is a considerable "sluggishness" happening in the gui window. Could this be alleviated through a better code writing? Thanks

Imports:

```
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
from random import randint
```

EDIT: Added missed and necessary code
EDIT2: Included all the imports

Comment: The code isn't runnable (see [mcve]), so one can only guess. What about `self.show_frame(self.frames[StartPage])` instead of 
 `self.show_frame(StartPage)`?

Comment: I forgot to add the `show_frame()` function. It is now added alongside the `update_reading()` function. I could completely combine the code such that you could paste it on a python file and it would run (including all imports).

Comment: Ok so I've solved the issue, but i dont know where to post this so im going to post this in here

Comment: To provide an answer, press the "Post your answer" button.

Comment: I was going to edit the comment since I presses add comment accidentally. I'll add it here since another problem came up: By replacing the `f = plt.figure()` with `f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)`, the labels seems  to work now. However, the tkinter gui now is more sluggish. Even dragging the window takes forever to respond. Is there a better solution than this one? Thanks

Comment: @RudyMontoya Quite a mountain of code. I would suggest add only your imports and definitions, and explain what the problem is.